# Webworks with jquery $.post and phoneGap

Tags: jquery, cordova, blackberry-webworks

In an application developed with webworks, jquery version 1.6.4 and PhoneGap I have trouble using  $.post.
In other similar questions are solved using Ajax, but it was not my case.

He added part of my code to try to find the solution:

Index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
<title>Prueba</title>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/estilo.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/sunny/jquery-ui-1.8.21.custom.css" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/json2.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/cordova-1.9.0.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.6.4.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-ui-1.8.21.custom.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    // process the confirmation dialog result
    function onConfirmaSalir(button) {
        if (button == 2) {
            // si
            navigator.app.exitApp();
        }
    }

    // Show a custom confirmation dialog
    //
    function showConfirm() {
        navigator.notification.confirm(
            'Desea abandonar la aplicaci�n?',  // message
            onConfirmaSalir, // callback to invoke with index of button pressed
            'Salir',         // title
            'No,Si'          // buttonLabels
        );
    }

    // Handle the back button
    function onBackKeyDown() {
       showConfirm();
    } 

    // alert dialog dismissed
    function alertConexion() {
        // do something
    }

    function showErrorConexion() {
        navigator.notification.alert(
            'Sin conexion, intente nuevamente',  // message
            alertConexion,         // callback
            'Error',            // title
            'Ok'                  // buttonName
        );
    }

    function checkConnection() {
            var networkState = navigator.network.connection.type;
            if (networkState == Connection.NONE) {
                return false;
            } else {
                return true;
            }
    }

    function cargarTabla(inicio) {
        $.post("http://sitio.com/", 
                { 
                },
                function(datos) {
                    $('#tabla').html('<article>'+datos+'</article>');
                }
        );
    }

     // PhoneGap is ready
    function onDeviceReady() {
        document.addEventListener("backbutton", onBackKeyDown, false);

        if (checkConnection()) {
            cargarTabla(1);
        } else {
            showErrorConexion();
        }
    }

    // phonegap
    function onBodyLoad()
    {
        // Wait for PhoneGap to load
        document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);
    } 
</script>
</head>
<body onload="onBodyLoad();">

<header>
        <h1>Prueba</h1>
</header>
<section>
    <article>
        <p>Hola!</p>
    </article>
</section>
<section id="tabla">
    <article>
            <p>Cargando...</p>
    </article>
</section>
</body>
</html>
```

I generate a zipped file containing: css, ext (Contains .jar codova), img, config.xml, index.html, plugins.xml.

Packaging with:
bbwp path_zip -o path_out

Generates files OK but when running, does not change the contents of the "tabla" section in the html.

How can you use jQuery Post with PhoneGap and webworks? The same code works on Android.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you might not have specified the  element in the config file to access external resources.

Include the following in your config.xml file: `<access uri="http://sitio.com" subdomains="true"/>`

For more info, check out the access element documentation: https://developer.blackberry.com/html5/documentation/access_element_834677_11.html

Comment: Yes, I have added access to the configuration file. Apparently this is the problem: [link]http://supportforums.blackberry.com/t5/Web-and-WebWorks-Development/URGENT-PROBLEM-DEVICE-BOLD-9780-WebWorks-Crashing/td-p/1448375[/link]